# Is it possible to differentiate a route on the same path but with a query?

Tags: go, go-chi

I want to define methods on `/` and then on `/?`. So I did

```
r.Get("/", myHandlers.Get)
r.Get("/?id", myHandlers.GetById)
```

But when I hit `http://myurl/?id=xyz` I never go to the `GetById` method. How can I differentiate them better in Go Chi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query parameters are not part of the route handling. So you only need one handler for the GET request to "/" and then differentiate if the id parameter is set or not.

```
if id := r.URL.Query.Get("id"); id != "" {
    // call id function
} else {
    // call normal get function
}
```